# How to edit display of short description in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

The Magento cart shows the short description twice.

I am using Firegentos German setup, which seems to be responsible for the second short description.
I like to use the shorten description with the .... at the end.

Where can I edit this?
[image: Magento descrition in cart]

Answer (score 1):

Find the template file relevant to this page, 
For you its app/design/frontend/unique/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

You will need to remove/comment the following code:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), ‘short_description’) ?>



<div class="short-description">
<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?></div>
```

Or u can make the class short-description as hidden.

- You have to search with `getShortDescription()` to perform this.